# Удаление всех элементов, кроме списка нужных в javascript

Tags: javascript

Есть **div** элементы с классом **placeholder**, в каждом есть **data-name** с текстом

```
<div class="placeholder" data-name="one">one</div>
<div class="placeholder" data-name="two">two</div>
<div class="placeholder" data-name="three">three</div>
<div class="placeholder" data-name="four">four</div>
<div class="placeholder" data-name="five">five</div>
<div class="placeholder" data-name="six">six</div>
<div class="placeholder" data-name="seven">seven</div>
```

У меня есть список нужных имён: **one**, **four** и **six**. Нужно спрятать все остальные.

```
$(".placeholder").data('name') //Выдаёт значение name с первого div
```

Проблема ещё в том, что в именах встречаются скобки, ковычки, тире.

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(".placeholder").filter(function() {
  return ['one', 'four', 'six'].indexOf($(this).data('name')) === -1;
}).hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="placeholder" data-name="one">one</div>
<div class="placeholder" data-name="two">two</div>
<div class="placeholder" data-name="three">three</div>
<div class="placeholder" data-name="four">four</div>
<div class="placeholder" data-name="five">five</div>
<div class="placeholder" data-name="six">six</div>
<div class="placeholder" data-name="seven">seven</div>
```